# ampscript to check two condition in IF statement

Tags: ampscript

i have two condition to check one is the different types of programs and another one is sales office is equal to particular office code.
to dispaly the next 7 days meetings

below is my code let me know if any corrections needed

```
%%[ Var @rs,

if (@Opportunity:Account:SalesOffice__c == "FRP" AND (Program__c == "AY" OR 
 "AYP" OR "MLY" OR "MLYP"))

   then SET @rs =LookupOrderedRows("Meeting7days",5,"Meeting 
date","salesoffice","AAA") ]%%
 %%[ endif ]%%
 %%[ var  @rowCount 
 set @rowCount = rowcount(@rs) if @rowCount > 0 then ]%% 
 %%[ endif ]%%
```

Comment: what error you getting ?

Comment: I have to say that i am unfamiliar with the syntax how you can get salesforce attribute values but usually ampscript variables start with @. When this applies to variables/fields from other salesforce systems than one of your mistakes would be that Programm__c is not a variable. Furthermore one additional mistake is that you define a var @rs but followed by a colon, which is a mistake in ampscript because it expects another variable -> just delete that colon. For future codings i would encourage you to indent correctly -> reading code will be much easier then.

Comment: One additional thing: try to declare all your variables on top of your script. This is best practice and will give you a better overview

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here as I see a number of errors right off the bat. First you are declaring `@rs` but there's a comma at the end that line. Second, if you are using variables in AMPscript, they need to begin with `@`, i.e. `@Program__c`. Lastly, I'm not sure what all those colons are for and that `LookupRows` function is incomplete. Also what's with all the open and close `%%[` and `]%%` for? Just wrap it in one block.

Here are the steps you need to take:

1. Declare your variables (not required but is best practice)
2. Define your variables using `SET`
3. Try getting your `LookupRows` working before you wrap it in an `IF` statement
4. Once you're set with the `LookupRows`, wrap the code in your `IF` clause

Answer (score -1):

@Priynaka g try like this this is my code

```
%%[ Var @rs,

if (@Opportunity:Account:SalesOffice__c == "FRP" AND (Program__c == "AY" OR 
Program__c="AYP" OR Program__c="MLY" OR Program__c="MLYP"))then 
  SET @rs =LookupOrderedRows("Meeting7days",5,"Meeting 
date","salesoffice","AAA") ]%%
 %%[ endif ]%%
%%[ var  @rowCount 
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rs) if @rowCount > 0 then ]%% 
 %%[ endif ]%%
```

Comment: pkharries, we describe what is wrong and what could be done better. We do not just post code. The user might not even understand what you changed. Please add some explanation to your post and I remove my downvote.